# How to login of my skype business account using python?

Tags: python, skype, skype-for-business, ucwa

I want to write a python code that will sign in to skype business 2016 account.After doing few research, UCWA is the only way to do so.i am attaching the my account image below. As you can see , there is no password field.

So how to login using python??Any link would be helpful.

[skype image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXCwv.jpg)

p.s - i am using my business account id to sign-in and  i guess we only use id to sign in. (never saw any password field even in outlook or onedrive )

Comment: skype business accounts are integrated with AD creds i.e outlook laptop etc. so don't need to specify password explicitly so you may try the AD or the outlook creds. AD: Active Directory(can be other domain as well). Also please refrain from adding pics of the code

Comment: @error404 can you please elaborate how to do that??

Answer (score 1):

Skype for Business is a completely different product from Skype, and uses a different protocol.

SkPy is a client for Skype, not Skype for Business. You will need to use a different library to interact with Skype for Business -- one option appears to be [ucwa](https://pypi.org/project/ucwa/).

Comment: how to do that ?? Any example or code would be helpful